# Google Javascript Client library OAUTH asks for Offline Access permission, though it was never requested

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

My application interacts with Google with Javascript only. It asks for user profile access, email access and contacts management permissions.
Upon loading a page, the application checks if the user has already granted those permissions and obtains an access token if he had.

Here is some sample code:

```
var GoogleContacts = {
...
    checkAuth: function(){
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: googleKeys.clientId, 
            scope: googleKeys.scopes, 
            immediate: true
          }, 
          jQuery.proxy(this.handleAuthResult, this)
        );
    },
    askAuth: function(){
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: googleKeys.clientId, 
            scope: googleKeys.scopes, 
            immediate: false
          }, 
          jQuery.proxy(this.handleAuthResult, this)
        );
    }
...
}
```

....

```
function handleGoogleApiLoad(){
    gapi.client.setApiKey(googleKeys.apiKey);
    gapi.auth.init(function(){console.info('popup api ready')});
    setTimeout(function(){GoogleContacts.checkAuth();}, 300);
}
```

....

```
$('#emailButton').click(function() {
    if(!accessToken)
       GoogleContacts.askAuth();
    ...
});
```

Now, if user comes for the first time, he is asked the correct permissions when he pressed the "Send email" button. When user reloads a page, the seamless permissions check returns failure and when user hits a "send email" button, we open the Google authorization popup again, and it now asks for Offline Access permission.
 
  This seems incorrect as the JS api has no actual use for offline access. 
  Looks like this problem started after Google released the incremental auth feature: http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html
  Is this a bug that will soon be fixed, or should we change the code somehow to not confuse our users with weird permission requests?

**Update:**

I have tried to use the plus api and `gapi.auth.signIn()` method but with the same result. 
Apparently, this problem is scope-dependant, as when I use only the login scope, everything works as expected, but adding the Google Contacts access scope https:||www.google.com/m8/feeds/ always leads to the Offline Access request when entering page second time. Here is a fiddle to confirm this: http://jsfiddle.net/hjLM6/6/
This must be a bug and I really would like Google to deal with it soon, as it scares users away.

Comment: It might be an issue related to this: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/12/are-you-using-approvalpromptforce.html

Comment: I thought so, but it appears that until a user actually accepts the Offline Access permission, the immediate auth method fails, so I am forced to call the non-immediate one and it then asks for offline access.

Answer (score 0):

The `immediate:false` parameter in your `askAuth` method is the cause. The [post that Abraham mentions](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/12/are-you-using-approvalpromptforce.html) explains the background.

The `gapi.auth.authorize()` method should generally be avoided in most cases now that the [`gapi.auth.signIn()` method is available to handle programatic initiation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow) of the authorization flow and also you should make use of the dynamic callbacks. The information on [monitoring a user's session state](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/session-state) explains how and when to get your sign-in callback function to fire and how you can use the values within the auth result object to determine if they've previously authorized your app, signed in (or out) of your app, or signed in (or out) of google.

Your checkAuth and askAuth functions would effectively be combined to check the status of the auth result object and act accordingly. Your email button click event would trigger instead `gapi.auth.signIn()` with the necessary parameters and scopes for your app.

Comment: I am calling gapi.auth.authorize() with immediate: true  right upon the Google API load event. It always fails until the user has accepted the Online Access persmission, so I have no other choice then to fire up authorization popup with immediate:false
I just went to the gapi.auth.signIn() demo page and the behavior there is just the same.

Comment: The demo page is showing the behavour because it's using approvalprompt=force (I'm guessing for demo purposes) which the blog I linked to recommends against.

Comment: Ok, I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjLM6/5/) out of [this example](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow#step_4_initiate_the_sign-in_flow_with_javascript) and it still asks for Offline Access when you run it second time.
Maybe, the problem is related to the scopes I am using?

Comment: Hope, Google would acknowledge this as a bug

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same issue with drive.readonly scope, for what it's worth the way I worked around it is by always calling authorize with immediate = false. This isn't that bad because when you do this for an already authorized user, Google will open the popup for a fraction of a second but then will immediately close it (apparently making use of the chance to open the popup in the browser event handler in case the user does need to authorize).

Curiously, for localhost server where I previously used immediate = true, I continue to see requests for offline access - but on the production server I haven't seen seen them so far, fingers crossed.

Comment: I have tried that approach too. It still requests the offline access upon reentering the page :(
I guess, until Google guys wake up, the problem stays.